# android OutOfMemory issue when saving data

Tags: android, bitmap, drawing, byte, out-of-memory

What i am doing is drawing application and there are two function needed for this project is the undo and redo .. so i need to save a list of previous drawing after each time the user draw and pull up his finger from the screen ..

This is the code when saving previous drawing

```
    public void saveState() {

    State mUndoState = new State();
    saveState(mSurface.getBitmap(), mUndoState);
}

private void saveState(Bitmap bitmap, State state) {
    state.mBuffer = new byte[bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight()];
    Buffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(state.mBuffer);
    bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);
    mListUndoState.add(state);
    System.out.println("Size now: " + (mListUndoState.size() - 1));
    mListRedoState.clear();
    mListRedoState.add(state);
    // StylesFactory.saveState(state.stylesState);
}
    private static class State {
    byte[] mBuffer = null;
    // final HashMap<Integer, Object> stylesState = new HashMap<Integer,
    // Object>();
}
```

The problem is android devices only have 16 MB of heap memory .. what is the best way to deal with this issue? .. i can only save it to ListUndoState 7 to 10 times and then i got out of memory exception .. i want to get unlimited undo action or at least not less then 50 times.

Here is the full class that save the previous drawing for undo and redo.

```
package com.appshouse.drawgram.utli;

import java.nio.Buffer;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class HistoryHelper {
    private final Surface mSurface;
    private List<State> mListUndoState = new ArrayList<State>();
    private List<State> mListRedoState = new ArrayList<State>();


public HistoryHelper(Surface surface) {
    mSurface = surface;

}

public void undo() {
    int length = mListUndoState.size() - 1;

    if (length <= 0) {
        System.out.println("no element is list");
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("history undo size: " + length);
    restoreState(mSurface.getBitmap(), mListUndoState.get(length - 1));

    mListRedoState.add(mListUndoState.get(length));
    mListUndoState.remove(length);
}

public void redo() {
    int length = mListRedoState.size() - 1;

    if (length <= 0) {
        System.out.println("no element is list");
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("history undo size: " + length);
    restoreState(mSurface.getBitmap(), mListRedoState.get(length));
    mListUndoState.add(mListRedoState.get(length));
    mListRedoState.remove(length);

}

private void restoreState(Bitmap bitmap, State state) {
    Buffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(state.mBuffer);
    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(byteBuffer);
    // StylesFactory.restoreState(state.stylesState);
}

public void saveState() {
    State mUndoState = new State();
    saveState(mSurface.getBitmap(), mUndoState);
}

private void saveState(Bitmap bitmap, State state) {
    state.mBuffer = new byte[bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight()];
    Buffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(state.mBuffer);
    bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);
    mListUndoState.add(state);
    System.out.println("Size now: " + (mListUndoState.size() - 1));
    mListRedoState.clear();
    mListRedoState.add(state);
    // StylesFactory.saveState(state.stylesState);
}

private static class State {
    byte[] mBuffer = null;
    // final HashMap<Integer, Object> stylesState = new HashMap<Integer,
    // Object>();
}

}
```

Comment: If you save all state in memory like that, you can not store much state. I have 2 suggestion for you:
1. If you develope a drawing application, I think you should not save bitmap as a state. You can save the user action like: what kind of action: draw, erase,... and list of coordinates user reaction,...
Base of this you can undo 2. OR if you must save bitmap, I suggest you should save bitmap as file, dont keep much bitmap on memory, they make your app outofmemory error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hieuxit suggest i save the bitmap in file-cache to get ride of this problem but i don't know if this is the best solution .. so if anyone got better solution please provide it to me.

Here is what i change in the previous class

```
package com.appshouse.drawgram.utli;

import java.nio.Buffer;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HistoryHelper {
    private final Surface mSurface;
    int undoAvailable = 0;
    int redoAvailable = 0;
    Context context;

    public HistoryHelper(Context c, Surface surface) {
        mSurface = surface;
        context = c;
    }

    public void undo() {

        if (undoAvailable > 1) {
            undoAvailable--;
            new LoadRestoreState().execute();
            redoAvailable ++;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "End of Undo Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }
public void redo() {
    if(redoAvailable >= 1)
    {
        undoAvailable ++;
        new LoadRestoreState().execute();
        redoAvailable --;
    }else
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "End of Redo Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        .show();
    }
}


public void saveState() {
    new LoadSaveState().execute(mSurface.getBitmap());
}


private class LoadSaveState extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
        undoAvailable++;
        FileCache fileCache = new FileCache(context, String.valueOf(undoAvailable));
        String str_buffer = Common.getStringDrawing(params[0]);
        fileCache.writeFile(str_buffer);
        redoAvailable = 0;
        return null;
    }
}

private class LoadRestoreState extends AsyncTask<Void , Void, Void>
{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        FileCache getFileChach = new FileCache(context,
                String.valueOf(undoAvailable));
        String image_str = getFileChach.readFile();
        Bitmap drawing = Common.getBitmapFromString(image_str);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[drawing.getRowBytes()
                * drawing.getHeight()];
        Buffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer);
        drawing.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);
        byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer);
        mSurface.getBitmap().copyPixelsFromBuffer(byteBuffer);
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Where the FileCache class is:

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import android.content.Context;

    public class FileCache {

        private File cacheDir;
        private File TempFile;

        public FileCache(Context context, String Filename) {

            cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
            if (!cacheDir.exists())
                cacheDir.mkdirs();
            TempFile = new File(cacheDir.getPath(), Filename);
        }

        public void writeFile(String buffer)

 {
        FileWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new FileWriter(TempFile);
            writer.write(buffer);
            System.out.println(TempFile + " File - data: " + buffer.toString()
                    );
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }

    public String readFile() {
        String strLine = "";
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(TempFile);
            BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            while ((strLine = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(strLine + "\n");
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("get text String: "+text.toString());
        return text.toString();
    }

    public void clear() {
        File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();
        if (files == null)
            return;
        for (File f : files)
            f.delete();
    }

}
```

And Here is Two Function that i created in Common class:

```
public static String getStringDrawing(Bitmap bm) {
    String image_str = "";
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] byte_arr;
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
    byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
    image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);
    return image_str;
}

public static Bitmap getBitmapFromString(String img_str)
{
    Bitmap bmImg = null;
    try {
        byte[] encodeByte = null;
        encodeByte = Base64.decode(img_str);
        bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0,
                encodeByte.length);
        bmImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmImg);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bmImg;
}
```

of-course you need to download base64 class for converting the image to string and vice versa